# Node.js Stream back-pressure handling across process

Tags: node.js, node-streams

While streams are a great package in Node.js for back-pressure handling within process via events, In my setup i am running it across process will it give me the same back-pressure handling?

To explain my setup i am running 2 node.js apps one as parent and other as child via the `process.spawn` method. Since there is going to be a lot of data streaming between child process and parent process i `piped` their `stdin` and `stdout` in cross over fashion to each other via streams and i am streaming the data across them successfully..(Child Process=Producer & Parent Process=Consumer)

Question is what about back-pressure meaning if for some reason parent process went into a delay in processing or child is publishing data faster than what parent can handle in such cases will the back-pressure be automatically handled by streams encapsulation?

To test I did an forcefully delay on the parent app for consumption of stream and what i observed was there is no memory bloat happening in the child process which tells me something is handling the back-pressure.. my assumption is the fixed size of buffer for stdout may be the one who are pushing it back from overflowing is that assumption correct?

Answer (score 0):

Backpressure doesn't stop you to push data into the buffer, it's just a marker that you could obey not to bloat the buffer.

In your case I guess the buffer's size was still enough to keep your child stream data waiting the parent process to be able to process it without extra memory allocation.

To avoid backpressure problem you could use a paused stream and read data from it when it's available with `.on('readable', ...)` event.

Comment: Either i have not understood the answer or you have misunderstood the question, Node default encapsulations handles back-pressure by looking at the write function return value and waiting on drain event to empty the existing message.. then write further is my understanding, this all is nice when your consumer and producer are in the same process.. but my question is what happens when when they are across process since they cant serialize events across then does the stdin buffer size becomes the KPI to handle back-pressure?

Comment: @Laukik if you could share your example in github it would be nice. otherwise i could prepare myself on my free time maybe

Comment: @Laukik The answer is still valid. The OS will handle it the normal way by causing the pipe to not be writable. The writer will then be paused until it is writable. This is normal file I/O handling (the same as if you're writing a large file to disk) but applied to pipes. Network sockets work slightly differently using features of TCP to handle it but that interacts with timeouts where disk/pipe I/O normally don't.